# How to create a 2-word command discord.py?

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I want to make the bot perceive, for example, a command .voice open, but gives an error

```
Command "voice" is not found
```

```
@commands.command(
    name = "closevoice",
    aliases = ["voice close"],
    usage = "voice close",      
  )
  async def voice_close(self, ctx):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this in two ways.

One way is to create a command "voice" and just have it take in open and close as args.

```
@bot.command()
async def voice(self, ctx, arg1):
    if arg1 == "open":
        # DO SOMETHING
    elif arg1 == "close":
        # DO SOMETHING ELSE
```

Alternatively, instead of making a command, you could just have the bot monitor messages and look for "voice open" and "voice close".

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "voice open":
        # DO SOMETHING
    elif message.content == "voice close":
        # DO SOMETHING ELSE
```